# Use Azure portal to grant access to a Keyvault

Tags: c#, azure-keyvault, .net-6.0, azureportal

I am looking for a way to enable the access to a certain keyvault:

```
if (builder.Environment.IsProduction())
{
    builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(
        new Uri(configuration["KeyVaultUri"]),
        new DefaultAzureCredential());
}
```

Can this be done using the Azure Portal (no Powershell, nor Azure CLI)?

Where do we say and check "this App can access this Keyvault using DefaultAzureCredential"?

***To clarify**: It is very basic stuff, I guess. I'm not trying to do anything tricky. The problem is that I have found documentation to do this using Azure-CLI, Powershell, and such. Also, you can bind the Keyvault to the App during the deployment setup (Visual Studio), which adds a lot of trash files to your solution... what I don't find is a source to do the same through Azure Portal*

**Edit**: What I have tried is:

1. In the Azure App Service configuration I have selected: Identity/System Assigned/Status: ON. I can see the App Service has now an Identity with an Object Id
2. In the Azure KeyVault configuration I have added a Policy whose Principal is the identity created in the previous step, with grants to read and list secrets

When I deploy the app, it crashes with no error logs. It just show an error page with 500.30 error. The documentation says it could be due to a missconfiguration of the Keyvault

The app starts without errors when I comment the following:

```
/*if (builder.Environment.IsProduction())
{
    builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(
        new Uri(configuration["KeyVaultUri"]),
        new DefaultAzureCredential());
}*/
```

Comment: Permissions for keys are at the vault level. In order to get the granularity that you want, you would have to create another key vault. check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/security-features#key-vault-access-policies

Comment: @Osamazx I already have a separate keyvault. How do I tell "App X have access to Keyvault Y"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Edit: What I have tried is:
>
> In the Azure App Service configuration I have selected:
> Identity/System Assigned/Status: ON. I can see the App Service has now
> an Identity with an Object Id
>
> In the Azure KeyVault configuration I have added a Policy whose
> Principal is the identity created in the previous step, with grants to
> read and list secrets

You ***have performed all the prerequisites to configure a Key Vault access from a App service*** . As you are already facing issue when you are not commenting the code snippet. Please don't use that code instead set it up from portal .

```
/*if (builder.Environment.IsProduction())
{
    builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(
        new Uri(configuration["KeyVaultUri"]),
        new DefaultAzureCredential());
}*/
```

***To configure it from portal , You can go to your*** ***`App service >> Configuration >> Application Setting >> + New Application Setting >> Provide Name as KEY_VAULT_URI and Value as your keyvault URI`***

[image]

You can refer this ***[`Microsoft Tutorial`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/app-service-msi-keyvault-dotnet/keyvault-msi-appservice-sample/)*** and ***[`Code Sample`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-msi-keyvault-dotnet/tree/master/WebAppKeyVault/WebAppKeyVault)*** for the same.

Comment: By adding the configuration suggested by you, it works! I don't need to remove the snippet. I think the problem was that, for some reason, KeyVaulUri is ignored from appSettings.json, thus a null keyvault uri is added to AddAzureKeyVault. I think the snippet is still needed, isn't it? How otherwise will Azure know that we will use the Keyvault?

Comment: @zameb, the key vault uri is added in the application settings .. so by default the app will connect with only that keyvault as we have added the managed identity in the access policy. as mentioned the microsoft documentaion i have shared

Comment: I don't understand. I have a few applications that are not using the keyvault. These applications don't have the AddAzureKeyVault() snippet. Now I want to use the Keyvault for one of these applications. How does Azure will know which app needs the keyvault and which one doesn't?

Comment: @zameb, those azure web apps which have keyvault uri set in application setting will be able to connect with the keyvault and those who don't have the uri set will not be able to do it ..

Comment: Got it, didn't know about this convention

Comment: glad to be of help @zameb :)

Comment: Adding to application settings in App Service isn't a solution. Once the application is published again, these values need to be rest again.